# want to save multiple records against one entity using sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, relational-database, dynamic-arrays, sonata-admin

I'm using sonata admin bundle and want to save multiple records against one entity. for example; I have three fields in my Entity (id, project, issues). suppose that a project has number of issues, I'm using multiple selection for the issues field, issues has ManyToOne relation with Issue entity, project has ManyToOne relation with Project entity,  i expecting prject_issues table something like this after save,

```
id | project| issues
--------------------
 1 |    2   |   23
 2 |    2   |   78
 3 |    2   |   45
 4 |    2   |   64
```

I'm very new to sonata admin and symfony2, how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Create three entities: `Project`, `Issue` and `ProjectIssue`. Create three admin classes for each of the entities. Create Doctrine `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjectIssue", mappedBy="project", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)` relation in `Project`. Create two `ManyToOne` relations from `ProjectIssue` to `Project` and to `Issue`. Use `app/console doctrine:generate:entities` command to generate correct setters and getters for one-to-many relation. Remember to add `$projectIssues->setProject($this);` in `Project::addProjectIssue($projectIssues)` method. Finally, do `->add('issues', 'sonata_type_collection', array('by_reference' => null), array('edit' => 'inline','inline' => 'table'))` in `ProjectAdmin`, and `->add('issue')` in `ProjectIssueAdmin`.

This will get you close to solution. Remember to define `__toString()` methods in your entities.

Answer (score 1):

You've to create (at least) two entities, lets name them `Project` and `Issue`, `Project` should be set up to have relationship OneToMany with `Issue`.
Having done that you should create admin classes for **both** entities and set them up according to SonataAdmin documentation. If you want only one of them to be directly accessible you might add `show_in_dashboard` set on `false` argument in service definition.
Next you'll wish to add this in your `ProjectAdmin`

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
   $formMapper
       ->add('issues', 'sonata_type_collection', ['by_reference' => null], 
               ['edit' => 'inline','inline' => 'table']
       )
}
```

You should be able to find reasons why `by_refference` and other arguments are set up like this in `SonataAdmin` docs.
If the above snippet does not work try adding `admin_code` pointing on the `IssueAdmin` service in the last argument.